# Returning to main function on Ruby?

Tags: ruby, return

I'm making a very simple code here to practice with Ruby and going to implement a simple "client, product, sell" interface

```
# Ohayou Sekai

num_clientes = 0
num_produtos = 0
num_vendas = 0
clientes = Array.new    #cria array de clientes
produtos = Array.new    #cria array de produtos
vendas = Array.new      #cria array de vendas

print "1 - Client
    2 - Product
    3 - Sale
    0 - Close program
    insert the manipulation code desired: ";
    end

init = gets.chomp
cont1 = "1"

while init != "0"
  
    ##### client manipulation #####
  
    while init == "1"
  
      puts "\n1 - Add client"
      puts "2 - Visualize registered clients"
      puts "3 - Edit client"
      puts "4 - Remove client"
      puts "0 - Return to previous menu"
      print "\nInsert the desired option: "
      cont1 = gets.chomp
```

Now the problem is: I'm entering good at the first while, but once in it, I'm struggling to return to the previous menu when the input for "cont1" is equal to 0

any idea of what I can do here ?

Comment: The code as posted can't possibly work, since you have a bunch of while statements with no end, and an end statement that has no referent. Please post a minimum, reproducible example of your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not clear on when to use an `if` statement and when to use a `while` loop.  Your code is also has lots of misplaced or missing `end` keywords, so it wouldn't even run at all.  I fixed all of that and made something that works:

```rb
@clientes = []
@produtos = []
@vendas = []

def client_manipulation
  while true
    print <<END
1 - Add client
2 - Visualize registered clients
3 - Edit client
4 - Remove client
0 - Return to previous menu
Insert the desired option:
END
    choice = gets.chomp
    return if choice == "0"
  end
end

while true
  print <<END
1 - Client
2 - Product
3 - Sale
0 - Close program
Insert the manipulation code desired:
END
  choice = gets.chomp
  client_manipulation if choice == "1"
  break if choice == "0"
end
```

I made your arrays at the top be instance variables so you can access them in multiple functions.  I also removed the variables like `@num_clientes` because you should just do `@clientes.size` if you need to get the number of clients.

Comment: actually the code is working at all, I just can't get back to the initial menu..
but thanks a lot dude ! since I'm still on the process of learning that language I'll have some work to understand everything on the code U wrote and adapt mine that surpasses more than 400 code lines but that's the objective, to learn Ruby

Comment: @Aderbalnevescalmetojunior: No, the code you posted *cannot possibly work* because it is not even syntactically legal Ruby. For example, on line #15 you have a closing `end` keyword with no corresponding opening `module`, `class`, `def`, `do`, `if`, `unless`, `while`, `until`, `for` / `in`, `case`, or `begin` keyword. On line #20, you have an opening `while` keyword without a corresponding closing `end` keyword, same on line #24.